# SlidingDrawer handle not displaying at top left corner

Tags: android

> Hii friends am creating sliding drawer i want to set it's handle at top left corner how to set there i have used relative layout and it's property android:layout_alignParentLeft & android:layout_alignParentTop are not supporting so how can i set handle there below is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >              


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/icon"            
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />                 
</RelativeLayout>

   <SlidingDrawer
       android:id="@+id/slider"
       android:rotation="180"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:content="@+id/content"
       android:handle="@+id/handle"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       >           

       <include
           android:id="@+id/content"
           layout="@layout/slider" />

       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/handle"
           android:layout_width="50dp"                             
           android:layout_height="50dp"               
           android:src="@drawable/handle" />          
   </SlidingDrawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-customized SlidingDrawer can only have its handles at the bottom or on the right.

You may want to take a look at Panel from misc-widgets https://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/

Otherwise you have to rotate your SlidingDrawer 180 degrees

```
android:rotation="180"
```

Sadly this is only available in Android 3.0+ (API Level 11)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to customize in this way the SlidingDrawable, but you can do it rotating the SlidingDrawable and its handle and content.
For example:

```
<SlidingDrawer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:handle="@+id/handle"
   android:content="@+id/content"
   android:rotation="180">

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/handle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="left" >

      <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:rotation="180" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#FF0000"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:rotation="180" />
</SlidingDrawer>
```